# Explanation for Schlafli's differential formula calculation of volumes.

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, spherical-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I want to get a detailed explanation (i.e via special cases and illustrations) of Schlafli's differential formula for calculation of n-dimensional volume. My motivation is to understand a result of Gauss on volume of hyperbolic tetrahedron. First let's write Schlafli's differential formula:

$$
dV = -\frac12 \sum_{ij}l_{ij} d \alpha_{ij},$$ where $l$ is the length of the edge, and $\alpha$ is the dihedral angle of the edge. I want to try and understand it first in the 2-dimensional non-euclidean case - by examples on spherical and hyperbolic triangles. After this, i still want to get explanation for the 3-dimensional spherical and hyperbolic case (by examples on spherical and hyperbolic polyhedra). I ask this question since it was difficult to find elementary discussions of this formula.

Thanks for everyone who will help me. This is such a wonderful website for getting answers to you questions.

Comment: Any triangle in $\mathbb{H}^2$ with angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ satisfies the property that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma<\pi$. In particular, an equilateral triangle with each angle being $\pi/3$ radians is impossible. This alone shows you that your intuition about hyperbolic geometry needs some refinement. I suggest picking up any book (Bonahon's book is great) and reading the introductory chapter about hyperbolic geometry. It's an amazing fact, which can be proved very easily, that similar triangles are congruent in hyperbolic space.

Comment: I know this fact (the angular deficit $\pi - \alpha - \beta - \gamma$ is equal to the area of the triangle when the constant curvature is $k = 1$) , but according to what i read schlafli's formula can be applied in any geometry - spherical, hyperbolic or euclidean.

Comment: i meant $k = -1$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @user2554: I don't have all the context, but there are some setups where the *absolute* measure of anything Euclidean is zero, even though you can still establish relative measures. So you might end up with Schläfli's formula telling you that the absolute volume of some Euclidean triangle is zero, even though compared to some reference triangle it shrinks. This is kind of a wild guess, though.

Comment: Where did you read that the formula could be applied to any geometry? Also you might want to edit your question to point out that although your question is tagged hyperbolic geometry, you are asking about the Euclidean case in your equilateral triangle example.

Comment: The book "Structural Properties of Polylogarithms"(at p.310) remarks that Schlafli first discovered this formula for spherical polyhedra (curvature $k>0$), and much later, Helmut Kneser found a proof that this formula is also valid for the hyperbolic case ($k<0$) . That it's also valid in the euclidean case ($k = 0$) is an addition of mine, which i wrote simply because it sounds logical that at the transition between spherical and hyperbolic geometry (i.e euclidean geometry) the formula will also be valid.

Comment: Since both elliptic and hyperbolic geometry have an intrinsic absolute measure which Euclidean geometry has not, I'd be far from certain about this. For both elliptic and hyperbolic geometry, the area of a polygon can be derived from the list of interior angles alone, which is not true for Euclidean geometry. So there are area-related situations where the Euclidean scenario is the odd one out. I think you should make it clear in your question that you are referring to an assumption of your own not one found in established literature.

Comment: Ok i'll change my question.